# Make AppleScript delay a random number between x and y?

Tags: applescript

```
set DelayTime1 to {18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58}
set DelayTime2 to some item of DelayTime1
delay DelayTime2
```

Is there any way I can clean this up so that if I want the range to be larger I don't have to type a bunch more numbers? i.e. `set DelayTime1 to 18 thru 58`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `random number`, e.g.:

```
set timeDelay to random number from 18 to 58
delay timeDelay
```

Or any `integer` *values* you wish.

---

For more information about [**random number**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW42) click the link.  Also have a look at: [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html)